# Open my app through Email

Tags: iphone, ios

Is there any way i can open my app through the email like suppose User A sends an xml file to User B through Email and when USer B click on it it open my app to extrat the tags from that xml file and show it to the User B.

Please answer this question, as i am middle of completing my app.

Thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a [custom URL scheme](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html) that your app responds to.

Comment: I am sorry but iam new to iphone development. Can you explain a little bit more so that i would be able to understand.

Comment: The link explains everything.

Comment: But this is for the apps you have on the server what about if i don't want to launch my app on server. Can we do the same thing for an app which exists in our phone

Comment: I am making this app just for the demo purpose and don't have to put it on the server. And by reading the link given above what i think is we can only open the app which is on server. Correct me if i am wrong. Thanks,

Comment: @Ashutosh, You do not need a server.

Comment: So what should i put in place of the url of the app... just the name of the app which is installed in my iphone through my Mac. Is that what you mean to say?? I am really sorry for bothering you but i really need to get this working. Thanks a ton !!!!

Comment: @Ashutosh, You can define a custom URL scheme as stated in the link that i provided. Once you've defined the scheme, when a hyperlink in an email is tapped that links to your scheme, your app will open.

Comment: How do you build the hyperlink? When I try linking to `myapp://` in an email from the gmail client or from Mail.app the link is stripped out.

Comment: @Jacob Relkin - If the app is not installed on the device, it would not work. How do I then redirect the user to the app store ?